# Convergence of sequence in topology

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology and came across the convergence of sequence which seems to be very counter-intuitive. I am stuck at the following question:

Let $x_n= (1, 1+(1/n))$. It says that the sequence is convergent in a Euclidean, Square metric and not in subway (taxicab?) and discrete metric. Explain and for converging sequence give their limits.

I can't understand how can we find the limit of an interval and determine how its converging. If its converging in one metric than it has to converge in other. Isn't that usually the case?

Comment: it seems to be a point of the plane! Two coordinates, the first is constant, the second is changing from point to point... By the way, the metric functions you mentioned indeed are related to topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: It's not an interval, it's a pair of real numbers. If the two metrics induce the same topology, a sequence converges in one if and only if it converges in the other. But the discrete metric induces a different topology than the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Can you please elaborate on "But the discrete metric induces a different topology than the Euclidean metric"

Comment: in the discrete metric the convergent sequences are preciesly the ones that are constant starting from some number, because the distance between distinct points is constant...

Answer (score 1):

The taxicab metric $d_t$ on $\Bbb R^2$ is given by

$$d_t\left(\langle x,y\rangle,\langle u,v\rangle\right)=|x-u|+|y-v|\;.$$

The sequence $$\left\langle\left\langle 1,1+\frac1n\right\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$$ converges to $\langle 1,1\rangle$ in both the Euclidean and the taxicab metrics, because in both the distance from $x_n=\left\langle 1,1+\frac1n\right\rangle$ to $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is $\frac1n$. I suspect that your subway metric is the metric that I’ve seen called the *New York subway metric*:

$$d_s\left(\langle x,y\rangle,\langle u,v\rangle\right)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\;,$$

so that the distance between two points is the sum of their ordinary Euclidean distances from the origin. In that case we have

$$\begin{align*}
d_s(x_n,\langle 1,1\rangle)&=\sqrt{1^2+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2}+\sqrt{1^2+1^2}\\
&=\sqrt{2+\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}}+\sqrt2\\
&\ge 2\sqrt2
\end{align*}$$

for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and the sequence definitely doesn’t converge to $\langle 1,1\rangle$. In principle it might converge to some other point $\langle a,b\rangle$, but in fact it doesn’t:

$$\begin{align*}
d_s(x_n,\langle a,b\rangle)&=\sqrt{1^2+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
&=\sqrt{2+\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
&\ge\sqrt2
\end{align*}$$

for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

The discrete metric $d_d$ is given by $$d_d(p,q)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }p=q\\1,&\text{if }p\ne q\end{cases}$$ for all $p,q\in\Bbb R^2$. Thus, if $p$ is any point of $\Bbb R^2$, there is at most one $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $p=x_n$ and hence at most one $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $d_d(x_n,p)<1$, and the sequence cannot converge to $p$.